# SparkSQL (Databricks): Insert data into Snowflake Table, created by different role

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, privileges, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table `MYSCHEMA.TEST_SNOWFLAKE_ROLE_T` in Snowflake created using the role `CONSOLE_USER.`

`MYSCHEMA` has a `FUTURE GRANTS` associated with it, which grants the following privileges to the role `BATCH_USER` for any table created under the schema `MYSCHEMA - DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, TRUNCATE, UPDATE.`

The role `BATCH_USER` also has `CREATE STAGE` and `USAGE` privileges on the schema `MYSCHEMA`.

A second user belonging to the role `BATCH_USER` tries to insert data into the same table from a dataframe, using the following Spark SQL (Databricks), but fails with an insufficient privileges error message.

```
df.write.mode(op_mode)                   \ 
  .format("snowflake")                   \ 
  .options(**self.sfoptions)             \
  .option("dbtable", snowflake_tbl_name) \
  .option("truncate_table", "on")        \
  .save
```

The following error message appears:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o908.save.
   : net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL access control error
   : Insufficient privileges to operate on table 'TEST_SNOWFLAKE_ROLE_T')
```

The role `CONSOLE_USER` has ownership rights on the table, hence the role `BATCH_USER` would not be able to drop the table, but adding the option `option("truncate_table", "on")` should have prevented automatic overwrite of the Table schema.

I've gone through the available Snowflake and Databricks documentation several times, but can't seem to figure out what is causing the insufficient privilege issue.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out eventually.

The error occured because the table was created by the role `CONSOLE_USER`, which retained ownership privileges on the table.

The Spark connector for Snowflake uses a [staging table](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html) for writing the data. If the data loading operation is successful, the original target table is dropped and the staging table is renamed to the original target table’s name.

Now, in order to rename a table or [swap](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html) two tables, the role used to perform the operation must have OWNERSHIP privileges on the table(s). In the situation above, the ownership was never transferred to the role `BATCH_USER`, hence the error.

```
df.write.mode(op_mode)                   \ 
  .format("snowflake")                   \ 
  .options(**self.sfoptions)             \
  .option("dbtable", snowflake_tbl_name) \
  .option("truncate_table", "on")        \
  .option("usestagingtable", "off")      \
  .save
```

The solution was to avoid using a staging table altogether, although going by the documentation, Snowflake recommends using one, pretty strongly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good reference for troubleshooting custom privileges: 
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html#role-hierarchy-and-privilege-inheritance

1. Is the second batch_user inheriting any privileges?
   Check on this by asking the user in their session to see what privileges they have on the table: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/show-grants.html
   What are the grants listed for the Batch_user having access issues to the following:

> SHOW GRANTS ON
>
> SHOW GRANTS OF ROLE
>
> SHOW FUTURE GRANTS IN SCHEMA {  }

2. Was a role specified for the second batch_user when they tried to write to "dbtable"?

   - "When a user attempts to execute an action on an object, Snowflake compares the privileges available in the user’s session against the privileges required on the object for that action. If the session has the required privileges on the object, the action is allowed." [ref:](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html#enforcement-model) 
     Try: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/use-role.html

3.Since you mentioned Future Grants were used on the objects created - FUTURE be ing limited to SECURITYADMIN via https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009MDCBv/can-a-role-have-rights-to-grant-future-rights

Comment: Thanks Rachel, I figured it out eventually. I'm not sure if there's a better solution available though.